# How does cygwin terminal work? (Makefile issue)

Tags: makefile, cygwin

Here's my makefile:

```
assemblera: main.o parsingA.o parsingC.o symbolTable.o
    gcc -o assemblera main.o parsingA.o parsingC.o symbolTable.o

main.o: main.c parsingA.h parsingC.h symbolTable.h
    gcc -c main.c

parsingA.o: parsingA.c parsingA.h
    gcc -c parsingA.c

parsingC.o: parsingC.c parsingC.h
    gcc -c parsingC.c

symbolTable.o: symbolTable.c symbolTable.h
    gcc -c symbolTable.c

clean:
    rm *.o assemblera
```

Now for the problem: with Windows command prompt I can easily generate all the .o files and .exe file, and if I run the latter it works as intended. Now, if I use the cygwin terminal, I can give the instructions to generate the object files / the exe, but those do not appear nowhere in the folder and no error is returned. Also, if I use the `make` command, it returns this error:

```
gcc -c main.c
make: *** [Makefile:5: main.o] Error 1
```

(I did put tabs in front of every "gcc" and "rm"). I know next to nothing about makefiles and cygwin.

Comment: what is the output of `file Makefile` ?

Comment: you should also explicitly define the output name also for the compiling phase `gcc -c main.c -o main.o`